# Add tab on new media library

Tags: media-library

hello I am trying to add new tab to the media library uploader:

[image]

My plugin currently only shows on the old wordpress media library:

[image]

**How do I add the tab to the select/upload media dialog?** Here is the code of the full plugin below:

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Sologet Upload Media From Url
Plugin URI: https://www.sologet.com/Thread-Sologet-Upload-Media-From-Url-Audio-Image
Author: Solomon (Sologet.com)
Author URI: http://sologet.com
Version: 1.0.0
Description: This plugin allows you to fetch the remote audio and save to your local wordpress without stress.
*/

class SologetUploadMediaFromUrl {

    var $audioName;

    function SologetUploadMediaFromUrl(){$this->__construct();}

    function __construct(){
        global $wp_version;

        if ($wp_version < 3.5) {
            if ( basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != "media-upload.php" ) return;
        } else {
            if ( basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != "media-upload.php" && basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != "post.php" && basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != "post-new.php") return;
        }

        add_filter("media_upload_tabs",array(&$this,"build_tab"));
        add_action("media_upload_SologetUploadMediaFromUrl", array(&$this, "menu_handle"));
    }

    /*
     * Merge an array into middle of another array
     *
     * @param array $array the array to insert
     * @param array $insert array to be inserted
     * @param int $position index of array
     */
    function array_insert(&$array, $insert, $position) {
        settype($array, "array");
        settype($insert, "array");
        settype($position, "int");

        //if pos is start, just merge them
        if($position==0) {
            $array = array_merge($insert, $array);
        } else {


            //if pos is end just merge them
            if($position >= (count($array)-1)) {
                $array = array_merge($array, $insert);
            } else {
                //split into head and tail, then merge head+inserted bit+tail
                $head = array_slice($array, 0, $position);
                $tail = array_slice($array, $position);
                $array = array_merge($head, $insert, $tail);
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }


    function build_tab($tabs) {
        $newtab = array('SologetUploadMediaFromUrl' => __('Sologet Upload Media From Url', 'SologetUploadMediaFromUrl'));
        return $this->array_insert($tabs, $newtab, 2);
        //return array_merge($tabs,$newtab);
    }
    function menu_handle() {
        return wp_iframe(array($this,"media_process"));
    }
    function fetch_audio($url) {
        if ( function_exists("curl_init") ) {
            return $this->curl_fetch_audio($url);
        } elseif ( ini_get("allow_url_fopen") ) {
            return $this->fopen_fetch_audio($url);
        }
    }
    function curl_fetch_audio($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $audio = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $audio;
    }
    function fopen_fetch_audio($url) {
        $audio = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        return $audio;
    }

    function media_process() {

        if ( $_POST['audiourl'] ) {
            $audiourl = $_POST['audiourl'];
            $audiourl = stripslashes($audiourl);
            $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
            $post_id = isset($_GET['post_id'])? (int) $_GET['post_id'] : 0;
            $ext = pathinfo( basename($audiourl) , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $newfilename = $_POST['newfilename'] ? $_POST['newfilename'] . "." . $ext : basename($audiourl);

            $filename = wp_unique_filename( $uploads['path'], $newfilename, $unique_filename_callback = null );
            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
            $fullpathfilename = $uploads['path'] . "/" . $filename;

            try {
                if ( !substr_count($wp_filetype['type'], "image") &&  !substr_count($wp_filetype['type'], "audio")) {
    throw new Exception( basename($audiourl) . ' is not a valid ' . $wp_filetype['type']  . '' );
}

                $audio_string = $this->fetch_audio($audiourl);
                $fileSaved = file_put_contents($uploads['path'] . "/" . $filename, $audio_string);
                if ( !$fileSaved ) {
                    throw new Exception("The file cannot be saved.");
                }

                $attachment = array(
                     'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                     'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
                     'post_content' => '',
                     'post_status' => 'inherit',
                     'guid' => $uploads['url'] . "/" . $filename
                );
                $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $fullpathfilename, $post_id );
                if ( !$attach_id ) {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to save record into database.");
                }
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $fullpathfilename );
                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $e->getMessage() . '</p></div>';
            }

        }
        media_upload_header();
        if ( !function_exists("curl_init") && !ini_get("allow_url_fopen") ) {
            echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p><b>cURL</b> or <b>allow_url_fopen</b> needs to be enabled. Please consult your server Administrator.</p></div>';
        } elseif ( $error ) {
            echo $error;
        } else {
            if ( $fileSaved && $attach_id ) {
                echo '<div id="message" class="updated"><p>File saved.</p></div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post" id="audio-form" class="media-upload-form type-form">
        <h3 clas s="media-title">Grab Audio Or Image from URL</h3>
        <div class="describe">Audio Or Image URL: 
        <input id="src" type="text" name="audiourl"><br/>
        Save as (optional) <input type="text" name="newfilename" style="width:200px">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Grab">
        </div>

        </form>
        <?php

        if ( $attach_id )  {
            $this->media_upload_type_form("audio", $errors, $attach_id);
        }
        ?>
        <div style="padding:10px;"><a href="https://www.sologet.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Sologet.com</strong></a> © <a href="https://www.sologet.com/User-Kingsolomon"><strong>Solomon Alozie</strong></a>

<a href="http://www.sologet.com"><strong>Hiding it difficulty to use this plugin or find any error </strong><strong>refer here for fix or help</strong></a>
</div>
        <?php
    }


    /*
     * modification from media.php function
     *
     * @param unknown_type $type
     * @param unknown_type $errors
     * @param unknown_type $id
     */
    function media_upload_type_form($type = 'file', $errors = null, $id = null) {

        $post_id = isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] )? intval( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) : 0;

        $form_action_url = admin_url("media-upload.php?type=$type&tab=type&post_id=$post_id");
        $form_action_url = apply_filters('media_upload_form_url', $form_action_url, $type);
        ?>

        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_attr($form_action_url); ?>" class="media-upload-form type-form validate" id="<?php echo $type; ?>-form">
        <input type="submit" class="hidden" name="save" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo (int) $post_id; ?>" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field('media-form'); ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        jQuery(function($){
            var preloaded = $(".media-item.preloaded");
            if ( preloaded.length > 0 ) {
                preloaded.each(function(){prepareMediaItem({id:this.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')},'');});
            }
            updateMediaForm();
        });
        //]]>
        </script>
        <div id="media-items">
        <?php
        if ( $id ) {
            if ( !is_wp_error($id) ) {
                add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'media_post_single_attachment_fields_to_edit', 10, 2);
                echo get_media_items( $id, $errors );
            } else {
                echo '<div id="media-upload-error">'.esc_html($id->get_error_message()).'</div>';
                exit;
            }
        }
        ?>
        </div>
        <p class="savebutton ml-submit">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="save" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save all changes' ); ?>" />
        </p>
        </form>

        <?php
    }
}

new SologetUploadMediaFromUrl();
?>
```

Comment: I see you used PHP 4 style action adders ( `&$this` ), you don't need the `&`, that was a PHP 4 compatibility fix, but WP hasn't supported PHP 4 in over a decade, and is incompatible. Please remove the PHP references on your `$this` variables, they're completely unnecessary and a bad habit

Comment: Please can help me and edit and resend pls boss

Comment: Literally ust replace every `&$this` with `$this`, note that this isn't an answer to your question, it's a comment about a separate thing

Comment: ok please can u give me help to my question ?

Comment: hmmm closer inspection reveals this is a 3rd party plugin from https://www.sologet.com/Thread-Sologet-Upload-Media-From-Url-Audio-Image **have you asked the sologet forum for support**? 3rd party plugins are offtopic here. You could ask how to add a tab to the uploader, but asking how to modify this plugin to do that on the other hand is free 3rd party dev support. I'd also note that you never actually say what the issue is, without looking at the screenshot it's not possible to tell as you never describe it fully in words

Comment: Am the sologet, i did an edit of old plugin and now the plugin last update was 4 yrs ago ,i edited it last week but the problem am facing is that on new wp version pls help out brother

Comment: Useful info while researching this, `media_upload_tabs` can be replaced with a new filter added in WP v3.5 that is more flexible: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_view_settings/

Comment: It would appear this has been asked before, and a solution was provided here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/313729/736